# vb6 - can I modify the treeview node key in vb6?

Tags: vb6

How can I change the tree view control node key in vb6?

I want to change it to another value on run time?

This is what i am trying to do:

```
treeview.nodes.key = "abc"
```

Comment: A guess off the top of my head is that you need to specify the Node's Index who's Key you want to change - `treeview.nodes(0).key = "abc"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change one or more node keys. What You are missing is to use the node index, or key in order to change it.
You can do si in two ways:

1. By using the node's key index:    TreeView1.Nodes(1).Key = "ChangedKey2"
2. By using the node's key: TreeView1.Nodes("MainKey").Key = "ChangedKey"

Hope this helps!